# Keyboard shortcut to delete the current rmd chunk in RStudio

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

There are keyboard shortcuts for inserting and running chunks. Is there a keyboard shortcut to delete the current chunk in R Markdown?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if such a feature exists. As of now, the trick I use to do it is folding the chunk and deleting the folded chunk.

[image]

You can also visit *[Shortcut: Select all in current R Markdown code chunk](https://community.rstudio.com/t/shortcut-select-all-in-current-r-markdown-code-chunk/17828)* to view *how* to select the whole chunk, as I believe this may help.

Comment: Thank you. It seems this feature does not exist. I also ask at RStudio Community.